# Get the count of bytes waiting on a serial port before reading

Tags: delphi, serial-port

I have a custom made device with which I send/receive data trough the serial port. I was wondering if there is any function I can use to get the count of bytes waiting to be read from the serial port?

I want only a windows api solution, if there exists one. It seems a trivial task and I don't want to use external components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ClearCommError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should fill in a [`COMSTAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (TComStat record) having a 'cbInQue' member specifying unread number of bytes received on the port.

Comment: Since you were the first to came up with an answer that fits the question i think you deserve it +1

Answer (score 4):

I use [TComPort](http://sourceforge.net/projects/comport/). Although you can use WinAPi calls, they are tricky and TComPort takes care of the boring stuff. It is very light and free and you can use the TComport.InputCount function which from the help:

```
 Returns the number of bytes in input buffer.

function InputCount: Integer;

Description
Call InputCount function to get the number of bytes in input buffer.
```

Comment: Under the hood it uses ClearCommError. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Win API **ClearCommError** should return the numbers of characters waiting in receiver buffer, where **cHandle** is currently used/opend serial communication port.

```
function TRS232Comm.InputCount: cardinal;
var
  Errors: Cardinal;
  CommStat: TComStat;
begin
  if not ClearCommError(cHandle, Errors, @CommStat) then
  begin
    PurgeComm(cHandle, PURGE_RXCLEAR);     //Just empty comm buffer on error and return 0
    result := 0;
  end else
    result := CommStat.cbInQue;
end;
```

Comment: ClearCommError failing does not mean there's nothing in the queue, you should inform what's wrong by calling `GetLastError`, not return '0'.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz: Right, but this is depended where and how you handle communication errors.

Comment: @GJ - Even so this would be a weird design. Considering the only point of your answer is to provide a code sample (since the api is already in an other answer), this feels wrong.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz: OK I have added RX clear buffer on comm error which I'm using later in my code when I'm calling GetLastError...

Comment: @GJ - I don't want to nick-pick till eternity but ClearCommError will also fail if you pass an invalid handle for instance, which then calling PurgeComm on the same handle will serve no purpose.. But thanks for edit anyway. :)