# Is there a way to check how many bytes are available to be read?

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port

I've been working on some stuff involving the Win32 API and Serial communications. I've managed to figure out how to open a COM port, and write/read to and from it, but I was wondering if there's a way to see how many bytes and/or characters are available to be read.
I was thinking maybe the `GetFileSizeEx()` function would work, but it doesn't seem like it.

I'm not entirely sure this question is very clear (as to what I'm looking for) so just to give a more obvious example, I'm hoping to find something like the Arduino's `Serial.available()` function

Here's my code thus far

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    HANDLE hFile;
    hFile = CreateFile("COM4",
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        0,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        0);

    if(hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cout << "bad handle" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    DCB cerialParams = {0};
    cerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(cerialParams);
    if(!GetCommState(hFile, &cerialParams)) {
        // error, but I'm too lazy to handle it.
        return 0;
    }

    cerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
    cerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
    cerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    cerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;

    if(!SetCommState(hFile, &cerialParams)) {
        // read above
        return 0;
    }

    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = {0};
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 500;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 500;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;

    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 500;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;

    if(!SetCommTimeouts(hFile, &timeouts)) {
        // do it again
        return 0;
    }
    
    BOOL success = 0;
    PLARGE_INTEGER fSizeStruct{0};
    //I've noticed that after I try to run this function, printing to the console no longer seems to work, oh well.
    success = GetFileSizeEx(hFile, fSizeStruct);
    std::cout << '"' << fSizeStruct << '"' << std::endl;
    std::cout << success;

    CloseHandle(hFile);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, there is no way to find out how much data you'll be getting in advance - the other side might not even have decided what to send yet. Why do you need to know this? (it hurts my eyes when you spell "serial" with a "c")

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I've gotten a pretty good answer (which I'll be checking out and possibly marking as correct) I'm making a messaging system for a project, and I want it to have all the features I'm likely to need (The messaging system is like 90% of the project) regarding the spelling of cerial, it's a joke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ClearCommError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-clearcommerror) function:

> Retrieves information about a communications error **and reports the current status of a communications device**.

The [COMSTAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/ns-winbase-comstat) struct it fills in has a `cbInQue` member:

> The number of bytes received by the serial provider but not yet read by a `ReadFile` operation.

Related/duplicate (in Delphi, but still applies here):

[Get the count of bytes waiting on a serial port before reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177284/)